# perl: how to check alphanumeric values and limit the string size to 30 by using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex for perl that would check for alphanumeric values (having spaces) but not including underscore "_" and limit the number of character to 30 I am trying this but this is not working could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong! This code is even taking special characters as alphanumeric values. $currLine = 'Kapil@ 123' this should not be a valid value.

** apologies by $currLine = "regex" i meant $currLine =~ "regex"

```
if ($currLine = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/){
say "Line3 Good: ", $currLine;
} else {
say "Error in Line 3: Name not alphamumeric "; 
}
```

Comment: When you say "having spaces" You want to accept spaces as valid? If so: you should also add a space so that it becomes `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`. If you want accept any whitespace char (tab, space, newline), use `\s`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$currLine = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/
```

means

```
$currLine = $_ =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/
```

You want to use

```
$currLine =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/
```

Now on to the other problems.

- You didn't allow spaces. (What follows allows whitespace. If you mean SPACE specifically, use that instead of `\s`).
- You allow a trailing newline.
- You allow 31 characters if the 31st is a newline.
- You forbid many alphanumeric characters.
- You forbid zero characters.

```
$currLine =~ /^[\p{Alnum}\s]{0,30}\z/
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using `=` (assignment) where you should have `=~` (bind).

Enabling warnings may have alerted you to this.  The code you have is matching `$_` and then assigning the results of the match to `$currLine`.

Answer (score 2):

For your regular expression to match all `alphanumeric values` including `spaces`, you need to include for space inside your character class. You should also be using the bind operator `=~` instead of `=` here.

```
if ( $currLine =~ /^[a-z0-9\s]{1,30}$/i ) { ...
```

**Note:** I included the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

You are using assignment operator(`=`) instead of match operator(`=~`). You should change the `if` statement to:

```
if ($currLine =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/)
```

This can also be shortened to:

```
if ($currLine =~ /^[^\W_]{1,30}$/)
```

`[^\W]` already matches anything apart from what is represented by `\w`. To discard `_`, we add it to negated character class, thus using - `[^\W_]`. Note however that, this matches much more than mere `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. It includes other unicode characters that come under word character. To just allow that regex to consider ASCII text, add [`/a` character set modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers):

```
/^[^\W_]{1,30}$/a
```

Comment: The two are not equivalent, except with the /a flag.

Comment: @ysth Yeah that will match much more including the unicode characters.